# Desktop problem

Tags: 13.10, dell

First time using ubuntu. I installed 13.10 and now when i start up the system it prompts me for a login. I login just fine, but once it loads there are no icons or menu of any kind. I can left click and drag to make boxes, and i can access all the options from right clicking (such as New Folder, New Document, Change Desktop Background, etc.) but that is it. I've read some forums about people logging out and switching to 2D, but I don't seem to have that option. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your computer have a graphics card? Do you see any messages when you start up?

Comment: No there is no graphics card, and the very first time I started up it said something about not having everything for the language, but it has not come up since then.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer isn't loading Compiz. Compiz is a resource heavy graphics thing that runs the Unity 3D desktop (the launcher, top panel, window effects, etc.)

It sounds to me like you may need to use a different desktop if you don't have a graphics card.

Ubuntu has a couple official flavors that use a lighter desktop.

Xubuntu: Uses the XFCE desktop. Has a panel on top that shows open windows and a application luancher on bottom. Simple menu in top left for finding installed applications and settings. [Link to Xubuntu website](http://xubuntu.org/)

Lubuntu: Uses the LXDE desktop. Has a single bottom panel that handles tasks and launchers. Has a simple menu in bottom left. Uses less memory (RAM) than XFCE. A little bit harder to use for a layman since some preferences do not have a GUI way of setting them. [Link to Lubuntu website](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Comment: So is there another Linux that can run without the graphics card, or is that what you're trying to say with Xubuntu?

Comment: It's what I'm trying to say. Xubuntu is still Ubuntu. It's just for older, less powerful hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time trying linux. I just built a computer the other day for gaming, so I grabbed an old computer from my friend's work to run linux so i can work on programming without worry of messing up my own stuff.

Comment: Just to point out, computer "without graphics card" can exist (for example something that would send output to printer or to punch cards), but i doubt that you have such a thing. Most likely it's built-in graphics that we are talking about here, not the lack of such.

Comment: Yes, when Dash asked I figured it was built in, but I don't know how to tell.